# Swift save multiple strings to core data

Tags: xcode, swift

I can save 1 string to core data, but what is the best way to save multiple strings to core data with minimal code? This is what I am working with:

```
            let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

            let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Custom", inManagedObjectContext: context)

            var newMessage = Custom(entity: ent!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)
            newMessage.words = "word1"
            context.save(nil)
```

Comment: Can you post your code for the strings?

Comment: At this point, I don't have any additional code. I would like separate buttons to add separate lists of words to core data. i.e. button1 would add word1, word2, and word3. button2 would add word4,word5 and word6. I am not sure how to do this without repeating all of the code above for each word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this using the `Transformable` attribute type in CoreData, which maps to a variable of type `id` in Objective-C or `AnyObject` in Swift.  You will be stuck with the overhead of having to unwrap and cast this to `[String]` or `NSArray` every time you want to work with it, but it'll get the job done.

Set up your entity like this:

[image]

And here's how your code would look:

```
class MyModel: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var strings: AnyObject?
}

var someModel = // Create your model
someModel.strings = [ "Hello", "World" ]
// Then save

// Later on, reload:
var reloadedModel = // Reload your model
if let strings = reloadedModel.strings as? [String] {
    print( "Strings = \(strings)" )
}
```

Another way I've done this is to make a new CoreData entity that just has a "name" attribute which stores the string, and then the parent object has an `NSSet` or `NSOrderedSet` of those objects as a relationship.  There is some cumbersome overhead to that as well, but it may be more appropriate depending on your needs.